# Shared Animations in Angular 7+

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Is it possible to share animation triggers throughout the entire project?

I don't want to add an import and animation meta declaration in every new component.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

### sharedAnimations.ts

```
import { trigger, transition, ... } from "@angular/animations";

export const sharedTrigger = trigger("sharedTrigger", [
    transition(":enter", [
       ...
    ])
])
```

### yourComponent.ts

```
import { sharedTrigger } from "./sharedAnimations";

@Component({
    ....,
    animations: [sharedTrigger]
})
....
```

Basically you can **reuse that shared trigger** everywhere, you just need to import it from module `sharedAnimations.ts`.
Hope that helps.

Comment: yeah, thats what I am doing right now. Just wanted to know if it was possible to declate the animation appwide, to skip the import and animations:[] part in my components.

Comment: I don't think it's possible